# How do I allow a script access to a file?

Tags: permissions, raspbian

I have a Python script that needs to open a file in a directory that I created: `/var/www/html/myDIR/myFILE.htm`
The directory needed to be created as root using `sudo mkdir /var/www/html/myDIR` as required by the parent folder.
As a result, my Python script cannot `touch /var/www/html/myDIR/myFILE.htm`.

What **minimum** permissions are required to allow scripts (that are not running as `root`) access to this file (or any file in this position)?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/q/19898/175814

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When creating the directory, set its group ownership to the same group as the user who will be running the script.  Include the group permission `g+wx`.  The script will then be able to create and edit files in that directory.

Comment: Thanks! Just now I actually used `sudo chown pi:pi /var/www/html/myDIR` and then `sudo chown pi:pi myFILE.htm` while in the directory, and that seemed to do it! This is essentially what you suggested, so I am accepting your answer. :)

Comment: This answer causes all programs, run by user, to have access to file.

Comment: No, it causes all programs run by a user in that specific group to have access to the file.  There is no (practical) limit to the number of groups.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor In my case, that would still be fine anyways.  Any file that I need executed by one script I'm likely to need run by a number of other scripts.

Answer (score 7):

@DopeGhoti's answer is great if you don't mind the all the user's programs  to have access to the file. If you only want the *specific script* to have access to the file, you can add an entry in `sudoers` file, so that the script is run with elevated permissions (not necessarily root) without the running user requiring any extra permissions.

Comment: And not just add the user, but also add more specifics to the `sudoers` record.